# Deserialized JSON data returning properties of "Nothing" in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization, shopify

This has been driving me mad for the past few days. I am connecting to the Shopify API and downloading JSON data. I have been able to successfully deserialize the data to an object using the class and code below. However, the object "customer" comes back with properties (as per the class) equal to "Nothing". What is going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! P.S. I should mention I am using Newtonsoft JSON.NET.

```
Partial Public Class ParsedJSON
    Public Class Customer2
        Public Property accepts_marketing As Boolean
        Public Property created_at As DateTime
        Public Property email As String
        Public Property first_name As String
        Public Property id As Integer
        Public Property last_name As String
        Public Property last_order_id As Integer
        Public Property multipass_identifier As Object
        Public Property note As Object
        Public Property orders_count As Integer
        Public Property state As String
        Public Property total_spent As String
        Public Property updated_at As DateTime
        Public Property verified_email As Boolean
        Public Property tags As String
        Public Property last_order_name As String
        Public Property default_address As DefaultAddress
    End Class
End Class

Partial Public Class ParsedJSON
    Public Class Order
        Public Property buyer_accepts_marketing As Boolean
        Public Property cancel_reason As Object
        Public Property cancelled_at As Object
        Public Property cart_token As String
        Public Property checkout_token As String
        Public Property closed_at As Object
        Public Property confirmed As Boolean
        Public Property created_at As DateTime
        Public Property currency As String
        Public Property email As String
        Public Property financial_status As String
        Public Property fulfillment_status As Object
        Public Property gateway As String
        Public Property id As Integer
        Public Property landing_site As String
        Public Property location_id As Object
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property note As String
        Public Property number As Integer
        Public Property reference As Object
        Public Property referring_site As String
        Public Property source As String
        Public Property source_identifier As Object
        Public Property source_name As String
        Public Property source_url As Object
        Public Property subtotal_price As String
        Public Property taxes_included As Boolean
        Public Property test As Boolean
        Public Property token As String
        Public Property total_discounts As String
        Public Property total_line_items_price As String
        Public Property total_price As String
        Public Property total_price_usd As String
        Public Property total_tax As String
        Public Property total_weight As Integer
        Public Property updated_at As DateTime
        Public Property user_id As Object
        Public Property browser_ip As Object
        Public Property landing_site_ref As Object
        Public Property order_number As Integer
        Public Property discount_codes As Object()
        Public Property note_attributes As Object()
        Public Property processing_method As String
        Public Property checkout_id As Integer
        Public Property tax_lines As TaxLine()
        Public Property tags As String
        Public Property line_items As LineItem()
        Public Property shipping_lines As ShippingLine()
        Public Property billing_address As BillingAddress
        Public Property shipping_address As ShippingAddress
        Public Property fulfillments As Object()
        Public Property client_details As ClientDetails
        Public Property customer As Customer2
    End Class
End Class

Partial Public Class ParsedJSON
    Public Property orders As Order()
End Class

... You get the idea
```

Now, here is my implementation code:

```
        ' Calls the method GetResponseStream to return the stream associated with the response. 

        Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")

        ' Pipes the response stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.  

        Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, encode)
        Dim json_data As String = readStream.ReadToEnd()

        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim customer As ParsedJSON.Customer2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ParsedJSON.Customer2)(json_data)
```

An example of the JSON data can be seen at http://docs.shopify.com/api/order.

Comment: Try: Dim customer As New IEnumerable(Of ParsedJSON.Customer2) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ParsedJSON.Customer2)(json_data)

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but it returned this error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ShopifyOrderManager.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Customer2' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ShopifyOrderManager.ParsedJSON+Customer2].`

Answer (score 0):

Code defensively. It is a well known issue that Shopify can provide Orders via the API that have null customer records. If you run into one of those, provide some safe defaults. Webhooks can receive orders with null customers too.

And when you fix your problem that bums out with valid customers, all will be well for you.

Comment: But I know that the JSON string has valid data in it. It's only when I'm trying to deserialize it that is giving null values..